# Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 label appearing as Containers and NOT File System

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, data-lake

I just started with Data Lakes in Azure and countered an issue with the ADLS Gen2 screens in the Azure Portal.

Using the Azure Portal, I created a new Storage account to setup a new Azure Data Lake Gen2 storage by following the online instructions. At the time of creating the storage account, the **option Hierarchical namespace was enabled** and the storage set to StorageV2(general purpose). This created the Data Lake. However the name of the container still appears as Container. In the videos i've seen the Services panel display the Container with the label 'Data Lake Gen2 File System'. However in the one i created it still shows the label as Container. Furthermore the collapsible panel to the left also shows Container as against File System. Please refer to the screen grab below.

Can anyone tell me on whether i am missing anything or is it just that Azure had changed the names in the immediate past that i am not aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything. Some time ago, we also noticed that the portal UI of ADLS GEN2 made the change: change the label **Data Lake Gen2 File System** to **Containers**.

It does not break any feature, just a simple UI change.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! Would appreciate if Azure follows an uniform and consistent naming pattern